# how can i stop HDMI streaming pragmatically android

Tags: android

I am making a android box app in which i need to show video running from my app and stop HDMI streaming for few mins then again start streaming as before and close app so basically i want switching between HDMi stream with my app 
1. Is it possible because i have read some of the links from google as they mentioned its a hardware issue i need sdk from box manufacturer 
2. i have gone through HDMI control from google but not found any thing relevant . So now looking for help from developer thanks

Comment: https://source.android.com/devices/tv/hdmi-cec - this is how to control HDMI in android hope this will help you.

Comment: But this api having a limited access like get port number and other not any option to complete control over HDMi like cut off